# Word for a woman who manipulates a man?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a single word other than *manipulator* for a woman who uses her sexuality to get a man to crush on her and then act as her champion for idiosyncratic reasons that have no basis in fact?

Comment: Not one word, but I was thinking "Lady Macbeth".

Comment: And I was thinking of that rude, offensive word, whose first letter is B. Sorry!

Comment: @Enguroo That is a good word, but not specific enough.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a **femme fatale**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/femme+fatale)

> an alluring or seductive woman, esp one who causes men to love her to
>   their own distress

As in:

> Inspired by “The Postman Always Rings Twice,” a superb
>   psychological-suspense tale starring an enigmatic **femme fatale**.
>       Washington Post May 21, 2018

or a **siren**, from Greek mythology  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/siren)

> a woman who is considered to be dangerously seductive

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use is **seductress**:

> A woman who seduces someone, especially one who entices a man into sexual activity.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seductress)</sub>

Surprisingly enough, [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=seductress)'s top definition for the word doesn't involve sex, but instead defines the word in a bit more nuanced way:

> Beautiful girl who has power and control over another person.